# New Relic Plugin with Custom Page

Tags: plugins, static, newrelic-platform

Since New Relic is a kind of “heart” of the operation of our IT Infrastructure, I would like to add static pages that has links to our Knowledge Base system, javascript based live debugging, etc.

I imagined something like to a Plugin that, instead of having graphs, it is HTML section to be show inside New Relic.

Is it possible?

Regards,
Vitor

Comment: Going in the other direction, you could create 'notes' for embedding on other sites that include links/text that you can edit. Dana's right though that we don't have a way to add informational sections to the New Relic user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this at this time with the New Relic User Interface. We always appreciate insight into the needs of our customers so we have submitted a feature request on your behalf and should such functionality become available you will be notified.

Thanks!
Dana
New Relic - Tech Support

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it to support users within your company, a firefox/chrome extension that injects the relevant content into the page could work.